# Variable value is not getting updated after adding an element to the array in apps script(Google Sheets)

Tags: google-apps-script

This is part of the code.

```
var newarray = [
  
  ["A","B"],
  
  ["C","D"]
  
  ];

var dimensions = newarray.length;

ss.getRange(15,8).setValue(dimensions);

newarray.push(["Bharat","Lata"])

ss.getRange(18,8).setValue(newarray.length);

ss.getRange(21,8).setValue(dimensions);
```

[Numbers in 15th, 18th, 21st row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XeuD.png)

I was expecting that dimensions value will be equal to 3 after adding an element to the newarray.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you're not updating the variable `dimensions` after pushing new row in `newarray`.

**Try following modification**:

```
var newarray = [["A","B"],["C","D"]];

var dimensions = newarray.length;

ss.getRange(15,8).setValue(dimensions);

newarray.push(["Bharat","Lata"])
 
dimensions = newarray.length;

ss.getRange(18,8).setValue(newarray.length); // you can use dimensions here too 

ss.getRange(21,8).setValue(dimensions);
```

Comment: I want to know the reason why it is not getting updated automatically. So basically whenever I add an element to the array, I have to update the variable dimensions.

Comment: Variables are not linked by reference to the other variable.  In your case the value of newarray.length is copied to dimension.  So now when ever newarray.length changes dimension is still the old value.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update also `var dimensions = newarray.length;` after updating `newarray`

```
function myFunction() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var newarray = [
    ["A", "B"],
    ["C", "D"]
  ];
  var dimensions = newarray.length;
  sh.getRange(15, 8).setValue(dimensions);
  newarray.push(["Bharat", "Lata"])
  dimensions = newarray.length;
  sh.getRange(18, 8).setValue(newarray.length);
  sh.getRange(21, 8).setValue(dimensions);
}
```

Comment: I would like to know - is there a way to create a variable, which gets updated automatically? Or I have to always use newarray.length to get the correct length?

Comment: You have to use `newarray.length` . I know that sometimes in javascript we can link objects together. It's not the case here.